# SQL Server simple WHERE clause extremely slow

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, performance

My SQL Server query is something like

```
Select * 
from mytable 
where mycolum = X
```

The table only has about 8000 records, and this query used to run extremely fast.

Now all of a sudden it's running super slow. Any thoughts? Here's what I've tried

- Updating the statistics for that table
- Shrinking the database
- Updating stats for the entire database via `sp_updatestats`
- Restarting the db server

None of these are working.

Any ideas or things I could try?

Comment: Can you share the query plan?

Comment: Some other query in progress? What does the server do? CPU / Disk capacity exceeded?

Comment: are you querying the database locally?

Comment: Consult [How do I Obtain a Query Execution Plan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/).

Comment: Build an index on `mycolum`.

Comment: If your query was running fast and now is running slow, either your data changed which could alter the statistics (and therefore the execution plan) or more likely something environmental is occurring. Check your Db server, network, client PC, etc.. to narrow down possible issues.

Comment: define "super slow" minutes ? Hours ? And prior ? How many recs now ? always 8000 ? How many columns ? There are binary columns ? Where are the db local or network ? What kind of type are mycolumn ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an index for the column.  If you are using a production DB that needs to remain active during the building of the index then you want to use ONLINE = ON in my sample below.

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_indx1 ON dbo.mytable (mycolum) WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

Comment: Online building/rebuilding indexes is a feature available only in Exterprise and Developer editions.